# Estimating the bias and variance of an estimator

Tags: variance, bias, mse

Suppose I have a vector of values generated by an estimator of $y$. I also have corresponding values of $y$ in another vector. Starting at the first observation, and adding the remaining observations sequentially, what algorithm will estimate the bias, the variance, and the MSE of the estimator?

**Update:** Following the comment by BruceET, let's narrow things and assume we know the estimator is a Normal random variable.

Comment: Exact estimates of mean and variance (an perhaps confidence intervals) may require knowledge of the distribution family. If you don't know the distribution family, perhaps use nonparametric bootstrap confidence intervals.Without more context the question seems too broad for helpful answers.

Comment: Suppose I know the random variable is Normal.